# msmtp not looking at keychain over ssh, only looks when in terminal

Tags: terminal, ssh, keychain

I've been wrestling with setting up msmtp for some time now, only to realize that when I run it from a terminal it works as expected (uses my password from my login keychain) but when I'm ssh'ed to the machine using the same user, it does not access the password from the keychain and fails login (or asks me for interactive login if I run msmtp directly).

How can I ssh to my machine and have msmtp fetch the password from my keychain?

Comment: Been investigating something similar myself.  Haven't had time to deeply investigate, but hopefully [this article](http://blog.macromates.com/2006/keychain-access-from-shell/) points you in the right direction. :)

Comment: @thankyour That looks promising, but when I run "security" during an ssh session, it does not return a password unfortunately (either with the -w or the -g option). It too only works in an actual terminal.